# Ubuntu and Belkin N150 f6d4050 Wireless USB adapter v2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, wireless-adapter

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I'm trying to get my Belkin USB adapter to work. There are plenty of discussions out there already about this, but none really helped me out.

Here's what I've done -

- Installed ndiswrapper Installed
- ndisgtk Installed the driver
- (rt2870.inf) via ndisgtk

ndisgtk reported that the driver was installed and the hardware was present.

The green light on the adapter is solid green, which I assume means that Ubuntu is aware of it's presence. However, when I click the little wireless symbol at the navigation bar, there's no option to choose my adapter (assuming that it's supposed to show up there...)

My adapter version is F6D4050 -

[image]

Where do I go from here? I'm a Ubuntu newb, so speak slowly. :P

lsusb -

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f9:0229 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 050d:935b Belkin Components 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsmod -

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc             7960  1 
fbcon                  39270  71 
tileblit                2487  1 fbcon
font                    8053  1 fbcon
bitblit                 5811  1 fbcon
softcursor              1565  1 bitblit
vga16fb                12757  0 
vgastate                9857  1 vga16fb
snd_cmipci             37557  2 
snd_intel8x0           31155  2 
snd_ac97_codec        125394  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                1450  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_mpu401              6875  0 
snd_pcm_oss            41394  0 
snd_mixer_oss          16299  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm                87882  4 snd_cmipci,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss
snd_opl3_lib           10846  1 snd_cmipci
snd_hwdep               6924  1 snd_opl3_lib
snd_mpu401_uart         6857  2 snd_cmipci,snd_mpu401
snd_seq_dummy           1782  0 
snd_seq_oss            31219  0 
snd_seq_midi            5829  0 
snd_rawmidi            23420  2 snd_mpu401_uart,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event      7267  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                57481  6 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
nouveau               515227  2 
ttm                    60847  1 nouveau
snd_timer              23649  3 snd_pcm,snd_opl3_lib,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          6888  6 snd_opl3_lib,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ns558                   3704  0 
ppdev                   6375  0 
drm_kms_helper         30742  1 nouveau
joydev                 11072  0 
ndiswrapper           244768  0 
gameport               10966  3 snd_cmipci,ns558
usblp                  12407  0 
asus_atk0110           10033  0 
parport_pc             29958  1 
serio_raw               4918  0 
drm                   199204  4 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            6024  1 nouveau
edac_core              45423  0 
edac_mce_amd            9278  0 
k8temp                  3912  0 
snd                    71106  23 

snd_cmipci,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_mpu401,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_opl3_lib,snd_hwdep,snd_mpu401_u

art,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore               8052  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          8500  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
i2c_nforce2             6099  0 
lp                      9336  0 
parport                37160  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
hid_logitech            8820  0 
ff_memless              5109  1 hid_logitech
ohci1394               30260  0 
usbhid                 41084  1 hid_logitech
hid                    83440  2 hid_logitech,usbhid
usb_storage            49833  0 
skge                   41049  0 
ieee1394               94771  1 ohci1394
sata_sil                8895  0 
forcedeth              55592  0 
sata_nv                23778  1 
pata_amd               11962  1 
floppy                 63156  0
```

Comment: Post `lsusb` and `lsmod`.

Comment: Updated question with the output of those.